# How to disable time passed in today jquery?

Tags: php, jquery

I'm new in Jquery.
Here is my problem. I would like to disable the time passed in today but not affect tomorrow time.
For example now is 31/03/2016 3:00pm, user cannot choose the time for 31/03/2016 2:00pm but able to choose time for 01/04/2016 2:00pm

Here is my jquery script code:

```
var dateTime;
$('#datepicker').datetimepicker({
    timepicker:false,
    format:'Y-m-d',
    formatDate:'Y-m-d',
    minDate: 0, // yesterday is minimum date
    maxDate: false, // and tommorow is maximum date calendar
    onSelect: function() { 
      dateTime = $(this).datetimepicker('getDate').getDate(); 
   }
});
if(dateTime  == new Date().getDate()){
    $('#reserv_time').datetimepicker({
    datepicker:false,
    format:'h:i A',
    step:5,                                          
    minTime: {hour: new Date().getHours(), minute: new Date().getMinutes()}
    })
}
else {
    $('#reserv_time').datetimepicker({
    datepicker:false,
    format:'h:i A',
    step: 5
    })
};
```

Here is my php code:

```
<tr>
<td width="24%">Date</td>
   <td><input type="text" id="datepicker" name="reserv_date" value="<?php echo date('Y-m-d');?>" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Time</td>
<td><input type="text" name="reserv_time" id="reserv_time" value="<?php echo date('h:i A');?>"/>
```

Thanks for help a lot.

Comment: Not clear what you are asking. Please, provide a working fiddle.

Comment: Hi, thanks to reply me. When user choose a date from datetimepicker in id="datepicker", and system will check the selected date is equal to today or not. If today, the system will disable the time (id="reserv_time") passed in today, perhaps able to choose any time.

Answer (score 0):

Add `minTime` also,

```
$('#datepicker').datetimepicker({
    timepicker:false,
    format:'Y-m-d',
    formatDate:'Y-m-d',
    minDate: 0, // yesterday is minimum date
    minTime: 0,  //Added Here
    maxDate: false, // and tommorow is maximum date calendar
    onChangeDateTime : enable,
    onSelect: function() { 
      dateTime = $(this).datetimepicker('getDate').getDate(); 
   }
});



var enable = function(currentDateTime){
        if(currentDateTime > new Date()){
            this.setOptions({
                  minTime:'0:00'
                });
        }
        else{
            this.setOptions({
                  minTime: 0
                });
        }
    };
```

Comment: This will disable all the time passed in everyday. I only like to disable the time passed in today. For example today is 31/3/2016 and current time is 4:00 PM. Time before 4:00 PM in today will be disable, but time before 4:00 PM in 01/4/2016 still available. User still able to choose 2:00 PM in 01/04/2016

Comment: If you change the date to next day all the time are enabled automatically..You cant select the passed time if the date is today

Comment: but it show not automatically. it will disable all the time before now for tomorrow too. :(

Comment: Can you please create and share the fiddle?

Comment: How you solved the problem post the answer which works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Thank for everyone to solve this question. I had found the solution.

```
var dateTime; 
$('#reserv_date').datetimepicker({
    timepicker: false,
    format:'Y-m-d',
    formatDate:'Y-m-d',
    minDate: 0,
    yearStart: 2015,
    maxDate: false
});
$('#reserv_date').on("change",function(){
dateTime = $('#reserv_date').val();
var d = new Date();
var month = d.getMonth()+1;
var day = d.getDate();
var output = d.getFullYear() + '-' + (month<10 ? '0' : '') + month + '-' +
(day<10 ? '0' : '') + day; 
if(dateTime  == output){
    $('#reserv_time').datetimepicker({
    datepicker:false,
    format:'h:i A',
    formatTime:'h:i A',
    step:15,                                             
    minTime: 0
    })
}
else {
    $('#reserv_time').datetimepicker({
    datepicker:false,
    format:'h:i A',
    formatTime:'h:i A',
    step:15,
    minTime: false
    })
}   
});
```